# Проблема в написании Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

```
CC=g++ 
PROJECT=sudoku
SOURCES= solver.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
HEADERS_PATH=include
LIBS_PATH=lib -llibz3

all:
    g++ -I$(HEADERS_PATH) -L$(LIBS_PATH) $(SOURCES) -o $@
test:
   make -f gtest/Makefile

run:
    make -f gtest/Makefile run

clean:
    rm -rf  $(OBJECTS)  $(PROJECT)
    make -f gtest/Makefile clean
```

после запуска make получаю ошибку:

```
g++ -Iinclude -Llib -llibz3 solver.cpp -o all
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibz3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

структура такая

```
include
|
|
lib
    libz3.lib
| 
|
solver.cpp
solver.h
|
|
gtest
```

что написано не верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Основная ошибка

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibz3
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Динамические библиотеки при передаче линкеру указываются или без суфикса и без префикса, или с путём до библиотеки. В большинстве систем GNU/Linux суффиксом является `.so`, а префиксом — `lib`, т.е. ключ должен выглядеть как `-lz3` или `-llib/libz3.so`.

Кроме того, судя по имени `libz3.lib`, не является динамической библиотекой GNU/Linux. Проверить можно, например с помощью утилиты `file`.

### Другие ошибки

> CC=g++

`CC` традиционно является компилятором языка Си; для компилятора С++ стоит использовать имя `CXX` или `CPP`

> LIBS_PATH=lib -llibz3

Валить всё в кучу таким образом — плохой тон; следует или отделить библиотеки от путей, или создать одну переменную под флаги линкера:

```
LD_FLAGS=-Llib -lz3
```

С путями к хедерам желательно поступить аналогично.

> ```
> all:
>     g++ -I$(HEADERS_PATH) -L$(LIBS_PATH) $(SOURCES) -o $@
> ```

Следует отделять компиляцию от линковки, для GNU `make` при этом можно использовать обобщённые правила:

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) -c -I$(HEADERS_PATH) -o $@ $<

А цели для линковки исполняемого файла давать осмысленное имя, а также указывать зависимости:

```
sudoku: $(OBJECTS)
     $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@
```

А у цели `all` уже указывать зависимость от неё:

```
all: sudoku

# ^ пустая строка.
```

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. После изменения BS_PATH=lib -llibz3 на D_FLAGS=-Llib -lz3 оишбка осталась та же самая. Если библиотека не динамическая то как ее подключить ?

Comment: Вы уверены в цифре 3 в названии библиотеки? Попробуйте `-lz`, это стандартная библиотека.

Comment: И если она у вас откуда-то привнесена уже в виде `libz3.lib`, то скорее всего она не подойдёт по формату. Из расширения видно что она собрана под Вин платформу, под *Никс вам нужен файл `libz3.a` или `libz3.so`, статическая и динамически собранные библиотеки соответственно.

Comment: @АртёмАртёмов, судя по имени это статическая библиотека под **другую** платформу, в таком случае, разумными средствами — ни как...

Comment: это сторонняя библиотека, компилировалась из исходников. Да,я вас понял, эта версия скомпилированная под win

Comment: @Fat-Zer, скомпиловал под linux (libz3.so), LD_FLAGS=-Llib -lz3. Теперь куча undefined reference

Comment: Соберите статично, чтобы получить суффикс файла библиотеки `.а`. Если вы все делали правильно, во время сборки библиотеки, то там вероятно не так декларированны функции. Или используется `.def` файл конфигурации, который gcc в расчет не берет.

Comment: И попробуйте сохранить предыдущее состояния `LD_FLAGS` - `LD_FLAGS=-Llib -L/usr/lib -lz3 $(LD_FLAGS)`

Comment: @АртёмАртёмов, смотря к чему не хватает ссылок... если к символам, которые есть в библиотеке (проверить можно `objdump -t libz3.so`), то скорей всего что-то не так указал... если символов к каким-то другим символам, то вероятно нужно ещё что-то скормить линкеру...